# How to replace the matched text with a word specifying by rules files?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am currently working on a Stanford CoreNLP program that replaces a matched text with a specified word using a list of given rules. I checked TokensRegex Expression, I know there is a regex function can be used in Action field:
`Replace(List&lt;CoreMap&gt;, tokensregex, replacement)<br>Match(String,regex,replacement)`
to do that. However, it is not clear to me how to implement this function in my rules files. And I couldn't find any example on GitHub or other web pages.

**Here is an example of a replacement:**

Input text: ***John Smith*** is a member of the NLP lab.

Matched pattern: "*John Smith*" is replaced with "*Student A*" in the text.

Resulting text: ***Student*** A is a member of the NLP lab.

Anyone could help me? I am new to Stanford CoreNLP and have a lot of things to learn.

Comment: Which programming language are you using CoreNLP with?

Comment: Hi, I use Java.